# watch not working properly in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written watch on pubInfoKey, But its not working properly when I set value to pubInfoKey in select function. What can be the problem here, I want to call Controller changeState method on pubInfoKey value change

Directive's link function :

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl, state) {
var pubInfoKey;
scope.$watch('pubInfoKey', function(val) {
    if (val) {
        $scope.changeState(val);
    }
}
);

var autoSuggest = element.autocomplete({

select: function(event, ui) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < scope.sug.length; i++)
    {
        if (scope.sug[i] === ui.item.value.toString())
        {
            pubInfoKey = scope.suggestionKey[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
});                             
}
```

Controller :

```
$scope.sug = [];
$scope.suggestionKey = [];
$scope.changeState = function(value) {
                //some code
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### $watch checks for scope properties on each $digest

- When I run your code I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`
- You also need `pubInfoKey` to be a property on a `scope`
- If autocomplete is a jQuery plugin then you need to trigger a `$digest`:

```js
var autoSuggest = element.autocomplete({
  select: function(event, ui) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < scope.sug.length; i++) {
      if (scope.sug[i] === ui.item.value.toString()) {
        scope.$apply(function(){        
          scope.pubInfoKey = scope.suggestionKey[i];          
        })
        break;
     }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes when I added pubInfoKey to scope its started watching it, but still when I set new value to pubInfoKey $watch is not getting called.

Comment: maybe your directive creates an isolated scope. please post more code.

Comment: Yes I think its because of isolated scope. I will go through it and then update the thread